# Q : Python CSV, Can rows of data from CSV be sent to a dataframe automatically based on the different date from datetime column

Tags: python, pandas, csv, datetime

[Sample CSV File](https://www.dropbox.com/s/8vpizm7mz1wir08/MainD2.csv?dl=0) can be viewed here

***Description of the Data:***

I have a huge amount of data where it has datetime column called `Time_Stamp` [ e.g. `2017/6/21 01:09:30`. The rows are created with each recording in seconds... so `2017/6/21 01:09:30`,`2017/6/21 01:09:31` and so forth. There are different dates as well with different timing for e.g `2017/6/22 03:38:43`.

***What I want to get:***

- Get the rows where the *date* of `Time_Stamp` is `2017/6/21 ..(time)..` into a Dataframe, followed by other *dates* like `2017/6/22 ..(time)..` into a separate Dataframe as well.

***My python code:***

```
import csv
from datetime import date,time,datetime
import pandas as pd


Data = pd.read_csv('MainD2.csv', parse_dates=['Time_Stamp'], infer_datetime_format=True)
Data['Date'] = Data.Time_Stamp.dt.date 
Data['Time'] = Data.Time_Stamp.dt.time 

Data['Time_Stamp'] = pd.to_datetime(Data['Time_Stamp'])
df = pd.DataFrame(Data)
```

**Below are the codes that I tried by manually getting timerange and dates:** - I want this to be automated but I'm not sure how to do -

```
countIC = 0
countIC2 = 0
countIC3 = 0
def getMask(start,end):
    mask = (df['Time_Stamp'] > start) & (df['Time_Stamp'] <= end)
    return mask

start = '2017-06-21 01:09:21'
end = '2017-06-21 01:18:54'
timerange1 = Data.loc[mask]

InputCurrent =timerange1.AC_Input_Current.tolist()

for i in InputCurrent:
    if float(i) >= 4.9:
        countIC += 1
        a = (countIC/60)
        a1 = (a/60)
    else:
        countIC2 += 1
        b = (countIC2/60)
        b1 = (b/60)
countIC3 = (a+b)
print ('Start: ', start, ' - ', 'End:', end ,' \n')
print ('%.2f' %a,'[in Mins]',' or ','%.2f' %a1,'[Hrs]',' of work') 
print ('%.2f' %b,'[in Mins]',' or ','%.2f' %b1,'[Hrs]',' of no work done')
print ('Total duration recorded: ','%.2f' %countIC3,'[Mins]')

countICC = 0
countIC22 = 0
countIC33 = 0

def getMask(start,end):
    mask1 = (df['Time_Stamp'] > start) & (df['Time_Stamp'] <= end)
    return mask1

start = '2017-06-21 19:54:20'
end = '2017-06-21 23:15:04'
timerange2 = Data.loc[mask1]

InputCurrent =timerange2.AC_Input_Current.tolist()

for i in InputCurrent:
    if float(i) >= 4.9:
        countICC += 1
        a = (countICC/60)
        a1 = (a/60)
    else:
        countIC22 += 1
        b = (countIC22/60)
        b1 = (b/60)
countIC33 = (a+b)
print ('Start: ', start, ' - ', 'End:', end ,' \n')
print ('%.2f' %a,'[in Mins]',' or ','%.2f' %a1,'[Hrs]',' of work') 
print ('%.2f' %b,'[in Mins]',' or ','%.2f' %b1,'[Hrs]',' of no work done')
print ('Total duration recorded: ','%.2f' %countIC33,'[Mins]')
```

***Output from code above:***

```
Start:  2017-06-21 01:09:21  -  End: 2017-06-21 01:18:54  

3.10 [in Mins]  or  0.05 [Hrs]  of work done
6.23 [in Mins]  or  0.10 [Hrs]  of No work done
Total Duration recorded:  9.33 [Mins]

Start:  2017-06-21 19:54:20  -  End: 2017-06-21 23:15:04  

125.00 [in Mins]  or  2.08 [Hrs]  of work done
472.38 [in Mins]  or  7.87 [Hrs]  of No work done
Total Duration recorded:  597.38 [Mins]
```

Comment: has it definitely to be a separate dataframe for each date? I think it would be easier to make one big df, and just filter the right date. And would you like the above output for each day, or for a selected time intervall?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all:
your code is very copy-paste like, you defined the function getMask two times, you only have to do this once. Same with your output string.

And your method of counting the working/non working times is not very good. You divide the final value through 60 in every iteration, you can make this at the end too.

However, pandas has very powerful tools to select, index and analyze your data. Try the code below:

```
    import csv
    from datetime import date,time,datetime 
    import pandas as pd

    def print_output(df):
        worktime = len(df.loc[df['AC_Input_Current'] >= 4.9])
        noworktime = len(df) - worktime

        print ('Start: ', df.index.min(), ' - ', 'End:', df.index.max())
        print ('%.2f' %(worktime/60),'[in Mins]',' or ','%.2f' %(worktime/3600),'[Hrs]',' of work') 
        print ('%.2f' %(noworktime/60),'[in Mins]',' or ','%.2f' %(noworktime/3600),'[Hrs]',' of no work done')
        print ('Total duration recorded: ','%.2f' %((noworktime + worktime)/60),'[Mins]\n')

    dateparse = lambda x: pd.datetime.strptime(x, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S')

    Data = pd.read_csv('MainD2.csv', parse_dates=['Time_Stamp'], date_parser = dateparse, index_col='Time_Stamp')

    print_output(Data['2017-06-23'].between_time('08:00', '23:15:04'))

    Data.resample('D').apply(lambda x: print_output(x))
```

*print_output()* prints a report over your selected data. The data is selected through the date and the *df.between_time()* method. Please take care, that the dataframe has now the datetime as index, unlike in your example.

If you want to make a daily report, you can use the *df.resample()* method and apply your own function, in this case the *print_output()*

This prints:
The first report is from the manual *print_output()* with the selected time, below are the daily reports.

```
    Start:  2017-06-23 08:43:31  -  End: 2017-06-23 23:10:15
    33.02 [in Mins]  or  0.55 [Hrs]  of work
    210.40 [in Mins]  or  3.51 [Hrs]  of no work done
    Total duration recorded:  243.42 [Mins]

    Start:  2017-06-21 01:09:21  -  End: 2017-06-21 23:15:04
    43.75 [in Mins]  or  0.73 [Hrs]  of work
    161.63 [in Mins]  or  2.69 [Hrs]  of no work done
    Total duration recorded:  205.38 [Mins]

    Start:  2017-06-22 00:38:54  -  End: 2017-06-22 05:47:29
    30.25 [in Mins]  or  0.50 [Hrs]  of work
    271.40 [in Mins]  or  4.52 [Hrs]  of no work done
    Total duration recorded:  301.65 [Mins]

    Start:  2017-06-23 00:39:50  -  End: 2017-06-23 23:10:15
    44.23 [in Mins]  or  0.74 [Hrs]  of work
    263.35 [in Mins]  or  4.39 [Hrs]  of no work done
    Total duration recorded:  307.58 [Mins]

    Start:  2017-06-24 00:38:10  -  End: 2017-06-24 13:33:49
    77.83 [in Mins]  or  1.30 [Hrs]  of work
    120.00 [in Mins]  or  2.00 [Hrs]  of no work done
    Total duration recorded:  197.83 [Mins]

    Start:  2017-06-25 09:54:25  -  End: 2017-06-25 20:16:05
    75.62 [in Mins]  or  1.26 [Hrs]  of work
    131.28 [in Mins]  or  2.19 [Hrs]  of no work done
    Total duration recorded:  206.90 [Mins]

    Start:  2017-06-26 00:51:32  -  End: 2017-06-26 01:05:55
    9.18 [in Mins]  or  0.15 [Hrs]  of work
    4.92 [in Mins]  or  0.08 [Hrs]  of no work done
    Total duration recorded:  14.10 [Mins]
```

Edit, plotting the data:

First of all, i'm not really familiar with matplotlib, so please refer to the documentation. This is only a very basic introduction.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

Then you can add at the end of your *print_output()* function:

```
df.AC_Input_Current.plot(kind='line')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Is it possible to plot a graph gor each dat as well? Pardon my bad python skills, im still pretty new to it

Comment: I've been running my python codes under Jupyter Notebook as a shell, but I have problems running my codes in the actualy Python IDLE or shell.. any idea why?